# Facebook Graph Api to get public page posts

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to get the posts from a public a page I have access to using Facebook graph API and Facebook PHP SDK. I want to do this with using a User Access Token but with the App access (APP ID and APP SECRET)

However, I can't work out how to get an access token that will allow me to use this with the correct permission. I was thinking that this would be the correct: **Page Public Content Access** how I don't know how to use it?

Comment: It’s a feature you need to submit your app for approval for first. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature#reference-PAGES_ACCESS

Comment: Ok but while my app is still in development it says that I can still use it but I don't understand how I use it @CBroe

Comment: It says, _“While you are testing your app and before you submit it for review, your app can only access content on a Page for which the following is true: The person who holds the admin role for the Page also holds an admin, developer, or tester role on the app.”_ So you will need to implement & test it under those conditions. But you will also need to use your user access token, because your app access token does not allow the API to check the connection between page admin role, and your role in the app. So any page access using an app token, will only work after you got PPCA approved.